# Can Data Explorer quantify over my votes?

Tags: discussion, data-dump, data-explorer

Can it be done in Data Explorer, or would I need the API for that?

I was thinking about how to write a query for the *Sportsmanship* badge, and I stumble on this.  I can see that there might be privacy issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way for a lay user to see what you have voted on.  Neither the API nor the data explorer allow it.

Mods can see some voting info, and the devs can see it all, but that's it.

Comment: And the Data Explorer must be a lay user, so accepted.  But can't the API tell me what I have voted on if I authenticate it?  I seem to recall someone saying it could do that.

Comment: @Charles, there is no authentication for the API right now.  Maybe this will be possible in version 2.